# Simple mod_rewrite rule not working [L]

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

So this is my first time doing mod_rewrite and I'm using tutorials and generators and it's been going okay so far except for the last line below which if I haven't made any mistake should redirect about.php to about/
Anybody know why it doesn't ?

All the other rules are working without issues (I did double check the page existed, I tried to add a slash before about.php as my website is on a server with multiple websites...)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

#Sub-dir e.g: /cmsms

RewriteBase /

#redirect www.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.metareviewr.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://metareviewr.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#RewriteRule ^show/([^/]*)/$ /tvshow.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^show/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /tvshow.php?id=$1&?name=$2 [L]

# Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)index\.php$ http://metareviewr.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^about/$ about.php [L]
```

Comment: Because it does the reverse, and doesn't redirect. It rewrites (internally) .../about/ to the about.php file, there are no external redirects there.

Comment: it does the reverse of what ? What it's supposed to do ?

Comment: The rewrite rule flag [L] means to stop if any condition is met. Here is a reference to all those flags. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html

You might need to move that rewrite rule above:
`# Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)index\.php$ http://metareviewr.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
RewriteRule ^about.php$ about/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: http://metareviewr.com/about/ gives me a not found (The requested URL /meta/about/ was not found on this server.) though it is there.

Comment: is your .htaccess file in the root of your directory? is the about page in the root also?

Comment: The root directory of the website, yes. Same for the about page.

Comment: For testing I would use absolute paths.